# Google Charts how to correctly represent % data without total sample figure

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

Hi Im creating Pie Charts using the Google Charts Library, the data that is been represented is browser stats of 2004, therefore the total sample figure is unknown, I mean it could be 85.3% of 1.2billion for all I know. But any way I have inserted my data as so via JS:

```
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Browser', '% of Usage'],
    ['IE', 76.2],
    ['Mozilla', 23.6],
    ['Netscape', 21.7],
    ['Opera', 1.6]
    ]);

var options = {
    title: "Browser Stats 2004",
    width: 300,
    pieStartAngle:100
        };
```

As you can see the figures I have inserted are already the % of usage and I don't need it to calculate the %'s for me. For example 76.2 for IE becomes 61.9%. I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/h6JfN/) so you guys are able to see what I mean.

What I want to be able to do is insert the figures as they are and for these to be represented in the pie chart?

Does anyone know how and where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Code is below or again view a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/h6JfN/).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Browser', '% of Usage'],
        ['IE', 76.2],
        ['Mozilla', 23.6],
        ['Netscape', 21.7],
        ['Opera', 1.6]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: "Browser Stats 2004",
        width: 300
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart2004browserstats'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<div id="piechart2004browserstats"></div>
```

Comment: @Tim Look at the figures I have told the JS to insert and compare what is representing them as i.e. I have inserted 76.2% for IE browser stats on the graph it represents this as 61.9%, it is obviously assuming that 76.2 is the figure out of 100 or something

Comment: Ah ok. Already deleted my comment. Just notcied that. all you need is an "other" category so that everything sums to 100.

Comment: Er... I would, but you have a problem. Your percents sum to more than 100%. There must be some overlap in the data somehow.

Comment: @Tim yeah your right the percent is well over 100%, i've noticed that some of my stats are incorrect.

Comment: I am not sure what is the best way to deal with that.

Comment: no your right as you said before, ensure that the figures total 100%. before they were not and 4% was missing and I read the source and it said that browsers that account for 0.5% are not included. Which then leads to believe this 4% is other. thanks for your help thus far, been good help

Comment: Ok, well the chart in your post can't be fixed as far as I can see. If you have a data set that for example totals 93.2%, then add an entry to your array `['Other', 6.8]`

Comment: Pie chart is not good for this representation because your data sum to more of 100%. My assumption is that some person reported as using two or even more browsers each day.

Comment: You can use bar chart and add another line `['All', 100]`. So, 76 persons used IE, 23 Mozilla...

Comment: Where did you get those data? IE and Opera seem correct, Mozilla and Netscape are completely off.

Comment: @AntoJurković thanks for the input but if you read the comments above you would have already ascertained that the figures were wrong and I checked them again and have made them equal 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My data wasn't totalling 100%, after checking the data and correcting the %'s were showing correctly.